# AJAX form onsubmit: jump to div

Tags: php, ajax

We currently search through a form for contacts, and AJAX is used to display the results from a PHP file below the form (on the same page). The form's `onsubmit` attribute includes a `return:false` value to allow the AJAX code to complete.

The results appear 'below the fold' and I'd like the focus to jump down to an ID (`#peopleResults`) but can't manage this; instead, it stays at the top of the parent page.

Should I be trying something in the actual PHP file or in the AJAX call (to the PHP file) to achieve this?

I already tried `<script>window.location.hash = "peopleResults";</script>` in the PHP file and referencing `results.php#peopleResults` in the AJAX call, but neither worked.

Is this possible? I guess I am trying to do the equivalent of appending `#peopleResults` to the URL upon pressing Submit (without the URL necessary changing)...

Comment: What I'd do is jump to the location after you get the AJAX data, and you've put it in the DOM, that should be doable.

Comment: Thanks @SLoW, where in the code (and how) would you jump to the location?

Answer (score 0):

> I already tried `<script>window.location.hash = "peopleResults";</script>`

`location.hash` *includes* the `#` – both when reading from it, as well when you *set* a new value.

So

```
window.location.hash = "#peopleResults"
```

would be the *correct* way to tell the browser to jump to an element with the ID (or anchor name) `peopleResults`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve this please check the [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ZT5Zu/1/).

This is done without using hash. As you just want to view the result after Ajax.

By this you don't need to change the URL.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the reply to my comment, it would seem you're a little foggy on the AJAX portion too.  From the documentation:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
  }
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
      //this is where you need to add your data to the div
      //after the data is in the div, scroll to it.
      console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
    }
  });
```

You can see, the function where I added the comments is where you need to do the scrolling.  After you populate the div (how ever you're doing that), then just use the suggestion Learner Student or phpisuber01 made of scrolling to it:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#peopleResults").scrollTop() }, 1000);
```

jQuery AJAX documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

jQuery scrollTop documentation: https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/